# How do I change the font size of small text in OpenTTD?

Tags: windows, openttd

I'm playing OpenTTD on a 2560x1440 monitor and the text on labels (when zoomed out) and maps are incredibly small, using letters that are only about 5 pixels in height:
[image: Buoy with small text]

[image: Map with many small labels]

The text is so tiny that it's starting to strain my eyes. How can I make it bigger?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two options available to you that solve this problem:

## 1. Game options

In the Game Options screen, accessed either through the main menu or from the gear icon in your toolbar, there is a dropdown menu that allows you to set the font size to Automatic, Normal, Double and Quadruple. Do note that this will affect *all* text, including text elements that have font sizes there's nothing wrong with.

[image: Game options menu]

**However**, if you'd rather only change the font size on those tiny labels..

## 2. OpenTTD.cfg

The `OpenTTD.cfg` file, located in the `%HOMEPATH%\Documents\OpenTTD\` folder, contains all the configuration variables used by your OpenTTD installation. You can change the font size of the small text used by labels and in the map UI by changing the following two variables:

```
small_font
small_size
```

By default, `small_font` is empty, and `small_size` is set at `0`. The size variables are only used when a font is defined, so setting the two variables like so:

```
small_font = Arial Bold
small_size = 10
```

Changes the font used on small text elements to something much more comfortable (click for full sizes):

[image]

[image]

I find that Arial Bold at 10px works really well, but it's worth experimenting a bit. Additionally you can also enable anti-aliasing by setting `small_aa` to `true` if that's something you fancy:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found [this article](https://yetgamer.com/openttd-how-to-make-text-readable/) that suggests the following changes to `OpenTTD.cfg`, which is located at `C:\Users\<your_user>\Documents\OpenTTD\`:

```
small_font = DejaVu Sans
medium_font = DejaVu Sans, Bold
large_font = DejaVu Serif, Bold
mono_font = DejaVu Sans Mono, Bold
small_size = 12
medium_size = 12
large_size = 16
mono_size = 12
```

The article directs you to substitute the existing 8 respective setting with these given and it worked pretty good for me. I was playing on a lesser resolution than 2560x1440 though.